# Creating animator file in Android Studio blocks app

Tags: android, animation, sharedpreferences, android-resources

I'm working on Android apps in Android Studio and need to add an animation to the project using an xml file.So I created a res/animator directory and I put in it a file called **pulsation.xml**,which do nothing, here the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:ordering="together">
</set>
```

Inside an Activity, the app access to some value stored in a **SharedPreferences** object.When running the apps without the **pulsation.xml** file in the res/animator directory the program retrieves the values needed without problems, when putting a **.xml** file inside **res/animator** the programs can't retrieve anything.I can't understand where this weird behavior come from. Here the piece  of code where the app retrieve the data from the SharedPreferences  object:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ballan.emmanuele.hellpuzzle.PUNTEGGI",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    do
            {
next = pref.getInt(R.id.liv1+"next",R.id.liv2);
                TextView punt = (TextView) findViewById(pref.getInt(next+"punt",R.id.punt1));
                punt.setText(pref.getInt(next+"punteggio",0)+"");
                TextView num = (TextView) findViewById(pref.getInt(next+"num",R.id.num1));
                num.setText(pref.getInt(next+"numero_sequenza",0)+"");
                LinearLayout lay =(LinearLayout)findViewById(pref.getInt(next+"riga",R.id.riga1));
                lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }while (next != ultimo);
```

I set the minimum SDK version to 11.Thanks for helping.

Comment: You mean `res/anim` directory?

Comment: in the $ res/animator directory for property animation directory

Comment: Ohh...my mad...apologies!

Comment: If you're on Android Studio and using Instant Run, completely uninstall the app and then retry after reinstalling from scratch

Comment: Ok I try to remove the project from Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem consists with Nexus S Api 23. Using this emulator the program still don't work, changing emulator or using my Samsung or other Nexus emulators phone the app doesn't bother.